# Load an external div or ul into a own webpage - from google/yahoo/facebook

Tags: php, jquery, include

Hey

Is it possible to get the content from a div or ul from another / external page (e.g. google facebook yahoo ...) if you know the page and the id from the div or ul?

if you use php - include, you'll include the whole page ... (too much)
with jquery .load(), i guess it is possible. Only i think it is slow and it will only work for webpages from the same domainname (not yahoo. bbc ....)

Can someone help me? or has someone more experience with it?

Kind regards

Comment: Is there an API to get the content you want?

Comment: You'd have to look at how the page is being constructed.  It might be using AJAX calls to get the information, or it might be part of the whole page.  We'd need more information about what you're trying to do

Comment: @Dagon The question is still valid and can apply to folks, including the OP, who may not use the answer for thievery. If we made assumptions as to the motives of every OP then SO would be a very judgmental place.

Comment: @Dagon 
Theft? is including your own facebook timeline theft?
If you know another way to include the facebook timeline (no app or fanpage) than can always leave a message to me :)

Comment: If that's what you wanted, that's is what you should of asked. There's an easy way to do that, the face book api.

Answer (score 3):

Create a php file called `x-request.php` off the root of the site and drop the following PHP code into it.

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://' . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

In the file you want to display the content add the following JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

    $('#selector').load('/x-request.php?url=google.com #container');

});
```

Replacing `#selector`, `#container` with relevant IDs and `google.com` with a relevant address.

The php file will get the whole page. The jQuery request to the php page will only get the id specified (`#container` in my example).

For more info see: Check out http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not exactly what you want but there's a way to make cross domain GET request. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

You might have to do the parsing, i'm not sure. I was playing with it last night and i was able to load the google.com page in my local page haha.

However, i think it might be better to go to API documentation of google, yahoo, facebook, etc to get something better for you.

Comment: +1 for recommending an API instead of scraping the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't request a particular portion of a webpage. The HTTP protocol doesn't allow for that - at most you can request a particular range of bytes, but then you'd need to know exactly WHERE your desired div is, and how big it is.

You'd have to fetch the ENTIRE page, use a dom operation to extract the relevant portion, then insert that. This won't work via Javascript, since you can't easily do 3rd party requests in JS. This would have to be a server-side operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can load and manipulate any HTML content with the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in PHP, which should be quite fast....